# Prevent the anchor tag in javascript part of the code from refreshing the page in an Elm single page application?

Tags: elm

I am trying to implement hash-less urls (like `/somePage`) in single page application.

I am now using `onPreventDefaultClick` from [here](https://github.com/elm-lang/html/issues/110), to prevent anchor links to refresh the page on click in my elm part of the code.

Problem is, I have a javascript editor embedded on the page. And there will be unpredictable number of links (which link to different functionalities on the app with different urls), on there also. How do I prevent them from refreshing the page. But also allow them to run the Command and change the url after that.

This was easy with hashed-urls like `/#/somePage`. In current implementation, I simply have hashed-urls in my anchor tags in the JS/editor part of the code, which just simply works by changing the url which fires my `PageChanged Page` Message. For this purpose I am using the [navigation package](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/navigation/2.1.0/Navigation) in elm.

Thanks!

Comment: Do let me know if my question is not clear enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Patch the editor to change the behavior of the links it generates. e.g. have the editor add an `click` handler that sends the event url through a port to Elm and return `false` (cancel the event).

Here is a minimal example that shows this:

Main.elm

```
port module Main exposing (..)

import Html exposing (..)


main =
    program
        { init = ( "", Cmd.none )
        , update = \msg _ -> (msg, Cmd.none )
        , view = view
        , subscriptions = \_ -> navigateTo identity
        }


view m =
    text <| "received: " ++ m


port navigateTo : (String -> msg) -> Sub msg
```

and a index.html

```
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    html {
      background: #F7F7F7;
      color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div> <a href="/first/link" onclick="return sendToElm(this);">First Link</a></div>
  <div> <a href="/second/link" onclick="return sendToElm(this);">Second Link</a></div>
  <script>
    var app = Elm.Main.fullscreen();
    sendToElm = function (el){
      app.ports.navigateTo.send(el.href);
      return false;
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

[Ellie link](https://ellie-app.com/37rpxrDHXmGa1/1)

Comment: I was afraid that something like this will have to be done. But I guess there is no way to do it without hacking the editor. Thank you.

Comment: You might be able to do something using Mutation Observers where you would add the event handers automatically if you can properly identify the links created by the editor (e.g. if the links have a certain class you might be able to detect their insertion into the DOM and add the above event handler.